# UPDATING a boolean in MYSQLI using PHP OOP

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

So basically, im trying to update a a boolean in my database from 0 to 1 whenever a button is clicked. The current code i currently have is this, which is not working.

```
<?php

require 'init.php';

if(isset($_GET['as'], $_GET['item'])){
$as = $_GET['as'];
$item = $_GET['item'];

switch ($as) {
    case 'done':
        $donequery = $db->prepare("
            UPDATE items
            SET done = 1
            WHERE id = :item
            ");

        $donequery->execute([
            'item' => $item
            ]);
        break;

}
}

header('location: index.php');
?>
```

The code for the index page has been added below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> To Do </title>

    <? //Google Fonts 

    require 'init.php';

    $itemsquery = $db->prepare("
            SELECT id, name, done FROM items
        ");

    $itemsquery->execute();

    $items = $itemsquery->rowCount() ? $itemsquery : [];


     ?>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans'           rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light+Two' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0m" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class='list'>
        <h1 class='header'/> To Do. </h1>

        <?php if(!empty($items)): ?>

        <ul class='items'>
            <?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
                <li>
                    <span class="item <?php echo $item['done'] ? ' done' : '' ?> "><?php echo $item['name']; ?></span>

                    <?php if(!$item['done']):?>
                    <a href="mark.php?as=done&item=<?php echo item['id'];?>" class='done-button'> Mark as done </a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>

    <?php else: ?>
        <p> You haven't added any items yet
    <?php endif; ?>

        <form class='item-add' action='add.php' method='POST'>
            <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Type a new item here' autocomplete='off' class='input' required/>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='add' class='submit'/>
        </form>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show the form please?

Answer (score 0):

You have a PHP error in your code, here: `<?php echo item['id'];?>`
You forgot the `$` sign